# Docker with Supervisor

Tags: docker, dockerfile, supervisord

I have created a docker file with Supervisor.
I have added 2 processes in the Supervisord properties file.
1st process for executing httpd or tomcat
2nd process will call sh file. The sh file contains echo and read command to accept user input and insert into property file.
Intention is to run 1st process in the background and 2nd process to wait for the user input.
While running the docker image, the 2nd process executing but not waiting for the input?

```
2021-02-09 16:46:32,901 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)  
2021-02-09 16:46:32,901 WARN No file matches via include "/etc/supervisord/*.conf"
2021-02-09 16:46:32,903 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2021-02-09 16:46:33,908 INFO spawned: 'supervisor_stdout' with pid 10
2021-02-09 16:46:33,911 INFO spawned: 'UserInput' with pid 11
2021-02-09 16:46:33,914 DEBG 'UserInput' stdout output:      
BMC_DATABASE_HOST:

2021-02-09 16:46:33,939 DEBG 'supervisor_stdout' stdout output:
READY

2021-02-09 16:46:33,940 DEBG supervisor_stdout: ACKNOWLEDGED -> READY
2021-02-09 16:46:34,942 INFO success: supervisor_stdout entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-02-09 16:46:34,942 INFO success: UserInput entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Comment: please post your configurations

Comment: Thanks Josh, I am still searching in this page, how to upload my configurations?  I can see only option "Answer Your Questions"

Comment: you embed them as part of your txt